# Trying to upgrade, from EF4.1 to EF6.1, ObjectContext reference code?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to upgrade my MVC3/.NET4.5 application to use EF6.1, in the main part for its performance improvements.

One of my problem code lines is :

```
        private AppEntities db = new AppEntities();
```

I have removed system.data.entity from references and web.config, but this line still seems to be looking for this dll. I did try and add:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext;
```

Did not seem to fix the issue with AppEntities line trying to find system.data.Entity v4.0.0.0

Many thanks

**EDIT**:

I managed to sort this by adding:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
```

to AppEntities.cs file.

Also needed to add to some of the POCO files.

```
using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
```

It all builds fine.

However my problem now is that it seems to take an age to show the page on first load, guess this is to do with native code creation. Also I have heard that much EF code that was native in .NET is now MSIL in Entity Framework.dll and thus need compiling to native code as well. Perhaps this is what is causing my pain, see:  [EF6 Warm up metrics](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/463997)

Comment: Did you try recreating your context using the new T4 templates for EF6?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have move on, but I believe I have now stumbled into another issues, that of the extended length of time take to initially create native code from MSIL, with EF.dll now requiring this.

Comment: I started on this upgrade for performance reasons, in particular the warm up issue, thinking that non compile SQL queries would also cause an issue, and EF6 does a lot to improve this I believe.

Comment: By the way I am using MVC3 and .NET4.5. Not sure if MVC3 would cause any slowness issue. Probably not as just a seperate set of .NET libraries.

Comment: It could be due to [view generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896240(v=vs.100).aspx) as well. How big is your model?

Comment: Thansk for comment. About 88 entities with some complex entities mapping onto the same physical table, but different columns. There is also TBH inheritance in use. I thought EF6 had greatly improved ViewGeneration features. Perhaps this load lag is due to Views being compiled up front whereas before they were not ie one get one hit upfront. The more I experience of all of this, the more I think I need to understand NGen, to do it properly up front.